# Using individual components

Tags: php, zend-framework

I've developed a web application using Zend 1.10 and would like to begin migrating to Zend 2, however I'm a bit daunted by the process based on the ZF2 online tutorials.

For Zend Framework 1, it was as simple as defining where my library was and instantiating the specific classes that I used for my project:

```
$library = '.:php/includes:/home/myusername/public_html/ZendFramework-1.11.11/library';
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $library); 
require_once('Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php');
Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
```

I'd then connect to my database using "$dbWrite = new Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql($config_stuff);" for example.

Is there not an analogously easy way of pulling classes from Zend 2 in a piecemeal manner as opposed to creating a full-blown Zend application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For completeness purposes, it is worth noting an alternative to @Divey's direct, correct, and useful answer.

You could use [Composer](http://getcomposer.org/) to grab individual ZF2 components. All the [ZF2 components are on Packagist](https://packagist.org/users/zendframework/)

The primary benefit is that you can grab just the component you need; no need to download the entire framework. Any cascading dependencies - ComponentX needs ComponentY to work - are magically detected (by ComponentX configuration) and installed.

Additionally, with Composer, you would have access to a whole ecosystem of classes - outside of ZF2 - that are available on Packagist (or just on Github itself, provided that the package is Composer-enabled) simply by adding a package to your project's `composer.json` file.

Comment: Thank you for this alternative, which may in fact better suit my needs.  It does present 2 additional questions, however. First, if I were to download the 5 or so components that I needed, should I still use autoloader to "find" those 5 classes or is there a better (quicker) alternative to loading them?  And, second, would it be more difficult to ensure that I have the most recent updates if I just get individual classes?

Comment: Autoloading with composer is very easy. Each Composer package describes its own autoloading and communicates that info to Composer. Composer then gives you a simple interface for accessing it: Just add `include vendor/autoload.php` in your project bootstrap/startup script and you're done. It really is sweet. ;-) Re: currency of packages: for each package that Packagist has in its registry, the source repo is crawled either once a week or on push (typically via a Github post-commit hook). For those packages that are not on Packagist, it's easy to point directly to the GH repo itself.

Comment: Thank you for the additional info!

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want [ZF2's Standard Autoloader](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.loader.standard-autoloader.html). Try using this:

```
require_once 'Zend/Loader/StandardAutoloader.php';
$loader = new Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader(array('autoregister_zf' => true));
$loader->register();
```